# "Give a rough estimate of the overhead incurred by each system call." - what?

Tags: java, resources, overhead

For a Uni assignment, I've written a Java program that `System.out.write`s chunk by chunk of text files to the console. We're doing some resource cost tests in Linux with the `time` command to see the execution time with different chunk sizes (chunk size is one of the arguments of the program). We're asked to:

> Write documentation where you explain the results of your time
>   measurements.  Can you give a rough estimate of the overhead incurred
>   by each system call?

I am confused by the last sentence. What exactly am I being asked to do?

1. What is overhead?
2. What does it mean when overhead has "incurred"?
3. How do I estimate amount of incurred overheads?

(Question 3) I may be able to answer myself if 1) and 2) is answered.)

Comment: For "incurred", I think "caused" is a close enough synonym.

Comment: Overhead in this context is "the amount of time spent in the system call, unrelated to doing the task at hand", which in your case appears to be "writing a string to stdout".